# Using jQuery in external .js file to handle click on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am using jQuery 2.0.2 on Debian 7.0.0.

I have set up a set of radio buttons thus.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th align="center" colspan="2" style="background:orange">Look Up Table</th>
</tr>
<tr align="left">
<td><input type="radio" name="LUT" id="GREY" value="GREY" onclick="EnableNonlinear()" 
    <?php echo $greyLUT ?>/>Gray</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="LUT" id="HOS" value="HOS" onclick="EnableNonlinear()"  
    <?php echo $hosLUT ?>/>Heated Object</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If I follow this block of code with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('input[name=LUT]').change(function(){
alert('Radio button clicked');
});
</script>
```

the alert box come up when I click on one of the radio buttons.  However, if instead I use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="DisplayOrAnalyzeSingleArray.js"></script>
```

and put

```
jQuery('input[name=LUT]').change(function(){
alert('Radio button clicked');
});
```

inside DisplayOrAnalyzeSingleArray.js nothing happens when I click on one of the radio buttons.  I do, however get the alert box coming up when teh page is loaded if I just put

```
alert('Radio button clicked');
```

inside DisplayOrAnalyzeSingleArray.js.

I am puzzled as to why the single alert statement works inside the external file, and the jQuery event handler works if I place it in the html code but the event handler does not work if I place it in the external file.

I am using Firebug 1.7.3 on Ice Weasel 10.0.12 but no error messages come up on the console.

Comment: Are you loading the JQuery file before the DisplayOrAnalyzeSingleArray.js file? Any errors showing (like jQuery not defined)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first make sure you are including your script after jquery -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DisplayOrAnalyzeSingleArray.js"></script>
```

and wrap your code in `.ready` handler

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('input[name=LUT]').change(function(){
    alert('Radio button clicked');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your code must me,

```
 $(document).ready( function({
    jQuery('input[name=LUT]').change(function(){
    alert('Radio button clicked');
    });
 });
```

Because, your code might be executed before the inclusion of .js file. To ensure that your code executes only after all the .js files are loaded you could include your actualy javascript code in a `.onready()` function like this.

Comment: When I tried this, Firebug gave me "missing : after property id: jQuery('input[name=LUT]').change(function(){ ".  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: OK.  It works when I make the top line "jQuery(document).ready( function(){".  Thanks again, Peter.